# What does system_clock::now() value after seconds represent in C++ 20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono, system-clock

I'm exploring the timestamp in C++ 20 returned from `system_clock::now()` and when I print out the returned  `std::chrono::time_point` it prints the date and time in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.xxxxxxx`.

Any idea what the `xxxxxxx` value is? I assumed microseconds initially but I realised microseconds are to six decimal places whereas this value is always to seven.

I'm running this in VS 2022.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto timeDate = zoned_time{ current_zone(), system_clock::now() };
    std::cout << timeDate << std::endl;  // Output: 2022-07-29 08:55:22.8582577 BST
}
```

Comment: Parts of a second.

Comment: And regarding the part "it returns the date and time in the format..." that's wrong. The internal format of the time-point is implementation defined, the format is part of the output and has nothing to do with the time-point returned by the `now` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can this be used to represent microseconds? I couldn't find documentation that mentioned what parts of a second represents relative to micro of milli seconds

Comment: `auto timeDateInMicroseconds = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(timeDate);`? See e.g. [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ch3qWPYnx) for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the fractional part of a second.

The output you're getting comes from `operator<<(zoned_time)`. This outputs the time in the format `"{:L%F %T %Z}"` (see [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time/operator_ltlt)). The `%T` part of the format is equivalent to `"%H:%M:%S"` ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time/formatter)) and the `%S` specifies the seconds as a decimal floating-point number with a precision matching that of the precision of the input (i.e. the precision of
`system_clock::now()` in your case).